# Testing React component method with jest && enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing

I've encounterd a question during testing React component with jest & enzyme. I'm used to mocking and testing a function which pass to Child component as props with `simulate()` of enzyme.

When I tested method in Component (which is not derived from parent) with spy, an interesting thing happened. I used `jest.spyOn` with enzyme's instance to test Component class method. Something likes this:

```
jest.spyOn(instance, 'Clicker')
```

and then I tried simulate event on element for invoking the method.

Case1 below failed:

```js
<button
      onClick={this.Clicker}
    >Click
 </button>
```

Case2 with Arrow function succeed:

```js
 <button
onClick={() => this.Clicker()}
>Click</button>
```

Both Component methods with Arrow function and function with `.bind(this)` on constructor have same result.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sn42 I just want to know why case1 failed. And I think I get answer now. It's probably because arrow function makes environment when it's invoked, so it is able to get function of this. however case 1 isn't